# Create grid in custom admin module

Tags: php, magento

I've created a custom admin module, but now, I wanna have a grid just like the Manage Customers, with the same functionality, this is for maintaining a standard between everything in the backend, I find the more I look less...please, need a hand here

Answer (score 0):

I have this in my config.xml but whn i click the Menu items it says Page404

```
<menu>
  <epslider module="epslider">
    <title>EPSlider</title>
    <sort_order>71</sort_order>
    <children>
      <items module="epslider">
        <title>Manage Items</title>
        <sort_order>0</sort_order>
        <action>adminhtml/epslider</action>
      </items>
    </children>
  </epslider>
</menu>
```

Comment: and i have this on top for my routers '<admin>
    <routers>
      <adminhtml>
        <args>
          <modules>
             <epwebwerx_epslider>EPWebWerx_EPSlider_Adminhtml</epwebwerx_epslider>
          </modules>
        </args>
      </adminhtml>
    </routers>
 </admin>   '

Comment: you should start a new question and try posting your full config.xml file